# Apache Lucene Indexer Search with CJKAnalyzer

Tags: java, apache, lucene, analyzer, indexer

```
             I am using Apache lucene Indexer Search to search text, and I am using
 CJKAnalyzer. It search provided word by character, It means 
 If I Search for Japanese word "ぁｘまｎ" , then its showing all 
 the words which is having any character of the provided Japanese word.
             But I dont want this I want search whole word or the 
 word which is having above mentioned word.
```

e.g. If I indexed 3 words. i.e "ぁｘまｎ" , "ぁｘま", "まｎ"

```
 case 1 :  If I search for "ぁｘまｎ" then it should only give one result.
 case 2 :  If I search for "ぁｘ" then it should give two result.
```

Now In my case If I search for the word "ぁｘまｎ" then its giving three results which is wrong.

------------------- Indexing  code ---------------------------------

```
writer = getIndexWriter();
List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
Document document1 = createDocument(1, "ぁｘまｎ", "Richard");
writer.addDocument(document1);
writer.commit();



 private static Document createDocument(Integer id, String firstName,  String lastName)
{
    Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new StringField("id", id.toString() , Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new TextField("firstName", firstName , Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new TextField("lastName", lastName , Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new TextField("website", website , Field.Store.YES));
    return document;
}


private static IndexWriter createWriter() throws IOException
{
    FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR).toFile());
    IndexWriterConfig config = new                                         
    IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44,new CJKAnalyzer());
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
    return writer;
}
```

--------call to Search ------

```
TopDocs foundDocs2 = searchByFirstName("*ぁｘまｎ*", searcher);
-------------------------------------------------------------
private static TopDocs searchByFirstName(String firstName, IndexSearcher searcher) throws Exception
{

        MultiFieldQueryParser mqp = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]{"firstName"}, new CJKAnalyzer());
        mqp.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
        Query q =mqp.parse(firstName);
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q, 10);
        return hits;
}
```

Comment: can you add your indexing code? what kind of fields do you use?

Comment: @dom I have added indexing code.

Comment: alright and your search code? do you use the same analyzer for searching too?

Comment: @dom yes I am using  same analyzer for searching.

Comment: hmm two things: try to analyse your index with luke https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke . And why using a multifieldQueryParser?

Comment: @dom because I am passing fields from bean. i.e I get searchable fields from bean and search for each attribute with given data. i.e my final searchable string[] is Project_Name:*abc* , Project_Type:*abc* like that.